# Industrial Economics Help

Tags: industrial-organisation

I am wondering if I have found q for all 3 firms correctly before I move on. I feel like I am doing something completely wrong, but can't seem to figure out what I truly need to do. (Sorry for the many pictures, I don't know another way to get post all of the information without doing it this way) Here is the question:[image]

Here is my work leading up to the answers I got for each q:

[image]

[image]

[image]